# Screen и запуск

Tags: debian, bash

Недавно понадобилось динамически открывать screen`ы, то есть, есть sh скрипт, который попросту запускает несколько screen окон для программ, должен, но не могу найти команды для того чтобы "screen ./script.sh" запустил скрипт, не разворачивая окна, сейчас при запуске sh, вылазит окно с выводом информации программы.

Comment: не очень хорошая идея использовать мультиплексор для запуска демонов.

Comment: Иначе бесконечный цикл не запустишь...

Comment: @eicto, как сделать демон из баш-скрипта?

Comment: `man screen` блин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen -d -m ./script.sh
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.